# getJSON callback issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to implement the following code to  read `json` data from a `url` which is in the form of

```
[{"name": "Adam", "country":"US","Age":"21"},{"name":"...."}]
```

I'm able to see the first log `console.log(here)` but it is not entering the second log `console.log(jsonhere)`, any thoughts on where I have made a mistake?

CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("here");
    var url = "url";

    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function (data) {
        console.log("jsonhere");
        $.each(data, function (idx, obj) {
            $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
                $('#tw2').append(key);
                console.log(key + ": " + value);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post what are you getting `console.log(data);`

Comment: are you able to check the response in dev tools?

Comment: @Satpal he doesnt get the second message. So the server might not return a successful reply. Right?

Comment: Does server handle jsonp at least???

Comment: It's clearly not a successful response if `"jsonhere"` isn't being output to console. That means there is an error in the request, or your server is having an issue handling the request. You could bind a function to the `error` handler. Or use fiddler/chrome developer tools/etc to see the response you are getting.

Comment: You could use a web proxy like fiddler to see the status code of the request and any details the server responds with as well

Comment: What is the `var url = "url";` did you use a real one, if not then the request has not been made at all.

Comment: Also, check the console for errors, do you see any errors ?

Comment: i used charles to see the response and it is showing just fine. i used an actual url, and marked it as url just for understanding. The content type is being show ans application/json

Answer (score -1):

The known issue for $.getJSON() is that it **caches** the response after the first request. If the same request is made (same URL and parameters), it will never hit the server. Instead, it picks the response from cache.

To force clear the cache for every request use:
`ajaxSetup({cache: false})` or

use `$.ajax()` with `dataType:'json' and cache:false`.

Comment: It's not even entering the handler.